# Apollo wrong directive call

Tags: graphql, apollo

For `userPasswordChange` mutation for some reason get called `minGroup` dirrective instead `idIsOwnerOrMinGroup`. What can be a problem?

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @minGroup(requires: Group = ADMINS) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION
  directive @idIsOwnerOrMinGroup(requires: Group = ADMINS) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION

type Mutation {
   userPasswordChange(oldPassword: String, newPassword: String!, id: Int!): Boolean! @idIsOwnerOrMinGroup(requires: ADMINS)
}`


import { MinGroupDirective } from '../directives/minGroupDirective'
import { IdIsOwnerOrMinGroupDirective } from '../directives/IdIsOwnerOrMinGroupDirective'

export const schemaDirectives = {
  minGroup: MinGroupDirective,
  idIsOwnerOrMinGroup: IdIsOwnerOrMinGroupDirective,
} as any

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives,
})

type MinGroupRequired = { _minGroup?: AccessGroup }
type MinGroupAvoidRewrap = { _minGroupAvoidRewrap?: true }

export class MinGroupDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitObject(type: GraphQLObjectType & MinGroupRequired): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(type)
    type._minGroup = this.args.requires
  }
  // Visitor methods for nested types like fields and arguments
  // also receive a details object that provides information about
  // the parent and grandparent types.
  visitFieldDefinition(
    field: GraphQLField<any, any> & MinGroupRequired,
    details: {
      field: GraphQLField<any, any>
      objectType: GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType
    }
  ): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(details.objectType)
    field._minGroup = this.args.requires
  }

  ensureFieldsWrapped(objectType: (GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType) & MinGroupRequired & MinGroupAvoidRewrap): any {
    // Mark the GraphQLObjectType object to avoid re-wrapping:
    if (objectType._minGroupAvoidRewrap) return
    objectType._minGroupAvoidRewrap = true

    const fields = objectType.getFields()

    Object.keys(fields).forEach((fieldName) => {
      const field = fields[fieldName] as GraphQLField<any, any, any> & MinGroupRequired
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field

      field.resolve = async function (...args): Promise<any> {
        // Get the required Group from the field first, falling back
        // to the objectType if no Group is required by the field:
        const requiredGroup = field._minGroup || objectType._minGroup

        if (!requiredGroup) return resolve.apply(this, args)

        const ctx: Ctx<CtxUserAny> = args[2]

        if (minGroupCheck(ctx.user.access_group, requiredGroup)) return resolve.apply(this, args)

        throw genGqlError('')
      }
    })
  }
}


type MinGroupRequired = { _minGroup?: AccessGroup }
type MinGroupAvoidRewrap = { _minGroupAvoidRewrap?: true }

export class IdIsOwnerOrMinGroupDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitObject(type: GraphQLObjectType & MinGroupRequired): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(type)
    type._minGroup = this.args.requires
  }
  // Visitor methods for nested types like fields and arguments
  // also receive a details object that provides information about
  // the parent and grandparent types.
  visitFieldDefinition(
    field: GraphQLField<any, any> & MinGroupRequired,
    details: {
      field: GraphQLField<any, any>
      objectType: GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType
    }
  ): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(details.objectType)
    field._minGroup = this.args.requires
  }

  ensureFieldsWrapped(objectType: (GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType) & MinGroupRequired & MinGroupAvoidRewrap): any {
    // Mark the GraphQLObjectType object to avoid re-wrapping:
    if (objectType._minGroupAvoidRewrap) return
    objectType._minGroupAvoidRewrap = true

    const fields = objectType.getFields()

    Object.keys(fields).forEach((fieldName) => {
      const field = fields[fieldName] as GraphQLField<any, any, any> & MinGroupRequired
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field

      field.resolve = async function (...args): Promise<any> {
        // Get the required Group from the field first, falling back
        // to the objectType if no Group is required by the field:
        const requiredGroup = field._minGroup || objectType._minGroup

        if (!requiredGroup) return resolve.apply(this, args)

        const ctx: Ctx<CtxUserAny> = args[2]
        const { id }: { id: number } = args[1]

        if (minGroupCheck(ctx.user.access_group, requiredGroup) || (id && id === (ctx.user as Ctx['user'])?.id))
          return resolve.apply(this, args)

        throw genGqlError('')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems they both called each time, not sure why.  After i changed dirrective from `field._minGroup` to `type._minGroupOrOwner` problem was solved. But i would like to see explanation.

```
type MinGroupOrOwnerRequired = { _minGroupOrOwner?: AccessGroup }
type MinGroupOrOwnerAvoidRewrap = { _minGroupOrOwnerAvoidRewrap?: true }

export class IdIsOwnerOrMinGroupDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitObject(type: GraphQLObjectType & MinGroupOrOwnerRequired): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(type)
    type._minGroupOrOwner = this.args.requires
  }
  // Visitor methods for nested types like fields and arguments
  // also receive a details object that provides information about
  // the parent and grandparent types.
  visitFieldDefinition(
    field: GraphQLField<any, any> & MinGroupOrOwnerRequired,
    details: {
      field: GraphQLField<any, any>
      objectType: GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType
    }
  ): void {
    this.ensureFieldsWrapped(details.objectType)
    field._minGroupOrOwner = this.args.requires
  }

  ensureFieldsWrapped(objectType: (GraphQLObjectType | GraphQLInterfaceType) & MinGroupOrOwnerRequired & MinGroupOrOwnerAvoidRewrap): any {
    // Mark the GraphQLObjectType object to avoid re-wrapping:
    if (objectType._minGroupOrOwnerAvoidRewrap) return
    objectType._minGroupOrOwnerAvoidRewrap = true

    const fields = objectType.getFields()

    Object.keys(fields).forEach((fieldName) => {
      const field = fields[fieldName] as GraphQLField<any, any, any> & MinGroupOrOwnerRequired
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field

      field.resolve = async function (...args): Promise<any> {
        // Get the required Group from the field first, falling back
        // to the objectType if no Group is required by the field:
        const requiredGroup = field._minGroupOrOwner || objectType._minGroupOrOwner

        if (!requiredGroup) return resolve.apply(this, args)

        const ctx: Ctx<CtxUserAny> = args[2]
        const { id }: { id: number } = args[1]

        if (minGroupCheck(ctx.user.access_group, requiredGroup) || (id && id === (ctx.user as Ctx['user'])?.id))
          return resolve.apply(this, args)

        throw genGqlError('')
      }
    })
  }
}
```